# In SQL, can I set the values of a column (age) automatically in the same table by solving the difference between the current date and birthdate?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can I set the values of a column (age) automatically in the same table  by solving the difference between the current date and birthdate? I am not talking about queries.

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT(
    Pnt_Lname varchar(50),
    Pnt_Fname varchar(50),
    Pnt_Mname varchar(50),
    Pnt_Birth Date,
    Pnt_Age numeric(5,0) 
    //TIMESTAMPDIFF(Date,CURDATE())
);
```

Comment: do not store age in a column, just calculate it during selection of records. in the end, you will be updating it every year.

Comment: You can create a calculated column: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268893/default-column-value-based-on-the-value-of-a-different-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't want to store this, but calculate it on every return.

What you want is called a "Computed Column".  From Microsoft's TechNet: "A computed column is computed from an expression that can use other columns in the same table. The expression can be a noncomputed column name, constant, function, and any combination of these connected by one or more operators. The expression cannot be a subquery."

You can read more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed field:

```
ALTER TABLE patient ADD Pnt_age AS DateDiff(year,pnt_birth,getDate()))
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx